# Where helper aliases of some of core modules defined?

Tags: helper, class, configuration

This confuses me a bit. I wonder why I didn't notice it before. When I look for helper definition of `Mage_Sales` core module, it surprised me that, I couldn't find helper defintion there. This confuses me a lot. Hence I tried this code

```
print_r(get_class(Mage::helper('sales')));
```

and it gave me this result

```
Mage_Sales_Helper_Data
```

Then where is the `sales` alias for `Mage_Sales_Helper_Data` is defined in magento. In other words, where should I can find this code snippet?

```
<global>
    <helpers>
         <sales>
             <class>Mage_Sales_Helper</class>
         </sales>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

I have also checked all xml files that are available for `Mage_Sales`'s etc module. None of them holds helper definition. So how magento assigned `sales` alias to helper class `Mage_Sales_Helper_Data`.

Please enlighten me with your valuable thoughts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sort answer is that it is not defined anywhere. If you trace back how `Mage::helper` works you get to the function `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName`

This will try to load any rewrites firstly, then the definition directly from the config and then finally just assume it starts with `mage_`

```
if (empty($className)) {
    if (!empty($config)) {
        $className = $config->getClassName();
    }
    if (empty($className)) {
        $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
    }
    if (!empty($class)) {
        $className .= '_'.$class;
    }

    $className = uc_words($className);
}
```

So in the end the class name will be `Mage_Sales_Helper_Data`, this is why when creating your own extension is you miss off the helper or other definitions you get an error that it is trying to looks for `Mage_Your_Module_Something`

Comment: Awasome .. @David ....upvote from me

Comment: I was digging in `getGroupedClassName()`. Now I am realizing.. I was so close to the answer !!. This completely wiped out my doubt. Now I can sleep with a calm mind. So +1 for make my mind clean :)

Comment: As @benmarks taught me, it's just a bunch of string manipulation to build class names that get autoloaded.

Answer (score 2):

With help of David above answer,Hope David would not mind.

**I am try explain more in detail**

start with Mage.php and go to function helper

```
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
        self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

a) `$registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;`

**result:** `$registryKey = _helper/sales`

b) `check now registry key exits ot not,if not then set a registry` variable

```
 if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
```

its becomes `true when system is first times` for a session:

c)  `$helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);`
that means

> $name=sales send to  Mage_Core_Model_Config class function
>   getHelperClassName
>           for getting helper class send param

d)Then set class `name is registry variable`e

```
 self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
```

**Result:** `may be proper class name Mage_Sales_Helper_Data`

**Now goes to  getHelperClassName function of class Mage_Core_Model_Config**

a) This function  Retrieve helper class name    string $name
      string

```
public function getHelperClassName($helperName)
{
    if (strpos($helperName, '/') === false) {
        $helperName .= '/data';
    }
    return $this->getGroupedClassName('helper', $helperName);
}
```

**explain of function:**

```
 $helperName is sales
```

the logic:

```
 if (strpos($helperName, '/') === false) {
```

becomes `true as $helperName=sales then set  $helperName=sales/data`

b)  `return $this->getGroupedClassName('helper', $helperName);`

**Details:**

```
call function getGroupedClassName with params 'helper','sales/data' 
and getGroupedClassName return    class name of helper class
```

**Now goto function** `getGroupedClassName('helper','sales/data',null)`

```
public function getGroupedClassName($groupType, $classId, $groupRootNode=null)
{
    if (empty($groupRootNode)) {
        $groupRootNode = 'global/'.$groupType.'s';
    }

    $classArr = explode('/', trim($classId));
    $group = $classArr[0];
    $class = !empty($classArr[1]) ? $classArr[1] : null;

    if (isset($this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class])) {
        return $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class];
    }

    $config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};

    // First - check maybe the entity class was rewritten
    $className = null;
    if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
        $className = (string)$config->rewrite->$class;
    } else {
        /**
         * Backwards compatibility for pre-MMDB extensions.
         * In MMDB release resource nodes <..._mysql4> were renamed to <..._resource>. So <deprecatedNode> is left
         * to keep name of previously used nodes, that still may be used by non-updated extensions.
         */
        if ($config->deprecatedNode) {
            $deprecatedNode = $config->deprecatedNode;
            $configOld = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->$deprecatedNode;
            if (isset($configOld->rewrite->$class)) {
                $className = (string) $configOld->rewrite->$class;
            }
        }
    }

    // Second - if entity is not rewritten then use class prefix to form class name
    if (empty($className)) {
        if (!empty($config)) {
            $className = $config->getClassName();
        }
        if (empty($className)) {
            $className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;
        }
        if (!empty($class)) {
            $className .= '_'.$class;
        }
        $className = uc_words($className);
    }

    $this->_classNameCache[$groupRootNode][$group][$class] = $className;
    return $className;
}
```

**this function task **

```
retrieve class name by class group
param   string $groupType currently supported helper
param   string $classId slash separated class identifier, ex. group/class
param   string $groupRootNode optional config path for group config
return  string
```

a)`$classArr = explode('/', trim($classId));`

**result:**`explode helper name(sales/data by /) for getting classs name in array $classArr`

b)`$class = !empty($classArr[1]) ? $classArr[1] : null;`

**Result:**`as $classArr[1] is  data then value of $class is data`

c)  `$config = $this->_xml->global->{$groupType.'s'}->{$group};`

**details:**`get config setting then $config = $this->_xml->global->helpers->sales;`

d)`$className = null;`

**Details:**`set $className  null`.

e) `check rewrite class exits in config.xml files, check if class is rewrite then
        you can easly get`
code: if (isset($config->rewrite->$class)) {
result:`if (isset($config->rewrite->data)) {`

f`)for default magento ,it false to goto else`

**skip if ($config->deprecatedNode) {**

```
 as deprecatedNode is for model($grouptype) and ,it only used for _mysql4
```

g) `if (empty($className)) {`

**result:**

```
if sales helper not rewrite then if (empty($className)) { becomes true
```

h`)if (!empty($config)) {`

**Result**

```
:false

if (!empty($config)) {  becomes false;`
```

i)  `if (empty($className)) {`
**Result:**`as $className is till
 null then this code is true`

j)  make class `$className = 'mage_'.$group.'_'.$groupType;`
**result:**

```
$group=sales
$groupTyp=helper
$className =  'mage_sales_helper';
```

k)

```
if (!empty($class)) {
                $className .= '_'.$class;
            }
```

**result:**

```
as $class = data the this condition  is true and $className =  'mage_sales_helper_data';
```

l)** make in upper case  `$className = uc_words($className)`;
Now return class return $className; which is Mage_Sales_Helper_Data**

Thanks to

**David Manners and Rajeev K Tomy**

Comment: Eventhough I have analysed this whole thing through mind, it is more understandable and helpful when it seems as this detailed answer. a big thanks for Amit who spend a lot of time to prepare this answer for me and for the entire community. Respect :)